# How to change a div attribute using a button in my ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 `div` that I want on the page. If the check from the `Div1` comes back true, I want the style of the `Div1` to change to `display:none` and the style of the `Div2` to be `display:contents`.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the `div` from my controller at all.

Here's what I have:
My HTML page:

```
<div id ="Div1" style="display:contents">

    <input type="text" asp-for="textinput/>

    <input  id="textchecker" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TextCheckerButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary/>

</div>

<div id="Div2" style="display:none">

    <input type="text" asp-for="textinput/>

    <input  id="textchecker2" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TextCheckerButton2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary/>

</div>
```

My controller code:

```
public void TextCheckerButton(MyClass data)
{

    if(data.Textbox1 == "qwerty")
    {
     // I want to set the display style of Div1 to display:none
     // and the style of Div2 to "display:contents" here
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm toying around with using ViewBags in my HTML.

I have tried using Viewbag and changing the value in my home controller methods. 
This does work in so far as changing the values when the page is loaded, but after going through the button click process, does not update either div on the webpage as intended. It feels like something obvious is missing.